# Why is this nginx www redirect not working?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, redirect

I'm having trouble with `www` redirects on an nginx server. The server is running 2 sites: `example.com` and `blog.example.com`.

Server config:

- nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Relevant DNS records:

- `www.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.`
- `blog.example.com. 1800 IN CNAME example.com.`

nginx configs:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com**

```
server {
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com/html;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/blog.example.com**

```
server {
  server_name blog.example.com;
  root /var/www/blog.example.com/html;
}
```

---

Expected: `www.example.com` redirects to `example.com`

Actual: `www.example.com` is displaying `blog.example.com`

Does anyone know why the redirect is not working as expected?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes I have, but that's a fair question. ;)

Comment: Create [an explicit default server](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/no-default) and if `www.example.com` returns a 444 - there is a typo in your `server_name` directive(s).

Comment: The question is missing `listen` directives from the server blocks, those affect also how virtual hosts go in nginx.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have a global config included that specifies the `listen 80;` directive.

Comment: @AD7six An explicit default server is a good idea. I'll do that and see if a 444 is returned.

Comment: @AD7six I added an explicit default server, but receive no 444 status codes. I'm beginning to think this is a DNS issue. When I view the `www` address of the site in Western Canada, it redirects as expected. However, when a friend views it in California, it displays the first website that's enabled (`blog.example.com`). The `www` CNAME record seems to check out for me: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#CNAME/www.grahamswan.com. It's almost as if certain locales don't see that CNAME record, so nginx doesn't know what they're looking for and simply shows them the first enabled site. Any thoughts?

Comment: dns just resolves the domain to an ip. The first thing to check is that "a friend" is talking to your server. e.g. `ping example.com` from "a friend"'s machine, is it your server's IP? You can test your setup using header injection e.g. this'll be a 444: `curl -I "Host: notconfigured.com" ip` and this should be a redirect: `curl -I "Host: www.example.com" ip`.

Comment: @AD7six I receive the expected `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` when I run `curl -H "Host: www.example.com" <ip>`. I'll check with my friend and see what response he receives.

Comment: Is http://example.com behaving as expected or does that show the blog site too?

Comment: @DougMcLean The `example.com` site behaves as expected.

Comment: Heh I just realised this question is from 10 months ago... I hope you got it resolved in the end?

Comment: It does work now, though I'm still not 100% sure why. Possibly a conflict that was resolved by updating certain packages. Whatever the case, I'm hoping I don't have to tackle this issue again. :D